# Why are my notes sounding so distinct and separate when I'm trying to play the Godfather theme on guitar?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, technique, amplifiers, solos

I have a Stratocaster and I'm playing the Godfather theme by Slash on it. I hit the notes right and I'm doing all the slides and vibratos. However, you know how the entire theme just flows when slash plays it? I mean one note just blends into the next. In my case, the notes all sound very distinct and that kills the 'feel' of the song. I mean if Slash sounds like '11122223333', I sound like '1-2-3'...hard to explain but I hope I was able to get my point across.

Is it that I'm not hitting the strings right? Or is it an amp setting? Currently, I'm using 'fuzz machine' and 'blue echo' in Garageband to get the "Slash" sound.

Here's a link to the Soundcloud recording I made:

Comment: A recording is worth a thousand words!

Comment: I have uploaded a recording on Soundcloud. Notice how the first part (intro) sounds fine, but the main riff sounds like distinct notes and doesn't flow. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I have an answer to your question, but I'd like to request that you re-write your question to be a bit more general in order to help future guitarists. Right now, it's a bit too specific to you.

Comment: I don't know how to describe my problem without being specific. I mean if I knew what's the general problem here, I would have the answer to my question.

Comment: Maybe try not plucking every note and instead hammering  it (softly) down with just the left hand?

Comment: A quick google on the youtubes shows slash playing this live. As @NeoScott mentions, approx 1/3-1/2 of the notes he plays are pull-offs and hammer-ons. Slash has always had a setup where you can really hear the pick attack, and when you cannot it is most likely a pull off etc. It sounds like you are plucking every note. He also takes his time and tries to be expressive--something that is far easier when one is a pro, since the basics of hitting the notes is basically autonomous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues there. I'll go for the obvious ones:

- you are taking too much time to change notes
- you are stopping a note before you play the next one
- you aren't using a compressor

Practice sorts out those first two - timing your pick hand and fretting hand will make a major difference. Slash plays some notes as hammer-ons and pull-offs as well.

A compressor also helps keep levels flat, which helps for a track like this

Comment: Clipping distortion acts a bit like a compressor...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. 1. I am a beginner so I definitely need to practice switching notes fast. But since the Godfather theme goes kind of slow I thought it wouldn't be too hard on me. 2. How do I not stop a note and let it ring before playing the next one? I mean I need to move my finger away from it to play the next. 3. I have added a 'squash compressor' pedal in Garageband. Would that help?

Comment: One great exercise to improve your fluidity is to pick a steady 1 2 3 4 rhythm and play the same note with every finger of the left hand. Start with pinky then ring then middle then first, but also practice starting with the index finger and going the other direction. Repeat smoothly in rhythm, same note, different finger every time you pick. You merely need thousands of hours of practice, like anyone else.

Comment: For your second point - as Jeremy said, you have more than one finger...